# Why was this question closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, flags, closed-questions

[Why Equals(null) fail on object array null check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911630/why-equalsnull-fail-on-object-array-null-check?rq=1)

While the question is a bit low-quality in the sense that the answer is trivial and the asker probably could have gotten it through research before asking, the question seems well within the rules. The reasoning states:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example.

The OP provided all the code, and the issue (experiencing an exception). Just because he did not provide the exception details does not seem like grounds for question closure.

Comment: This question was closed almost _two years ago_.

Comment: [DoesNotWorkException](http://imgur.com/gBCsyN7) <3

Comment: Why are different things different and behave differently and are different?  Because.  Now go to bed.

Comment: `This question was closed almost two years ago` that's not necessarily a reason not to question why it was closed, though. No?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option would be to close as duplicate of [C# difference between == and Equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814878/c-sharp-difference-between-and-equals) . There are also too many different answers that could have helped OP - so personally "duplicate", "lack of MCVE", "too broad", "unclear what you are asking" could be close reasons.

Lack of MCVE seem to be good reason to close this question: the real *minimal* example is (which is not complete, but at least possible to see what it could be).

```
if (null.AnyMethod())  //Throws exception
```

Some more effort on OP's side either by trying different things in they current sample would have clarified problem.

Likely OP did not understood concepts of getting value of element of an array or calling object's methods in language of they choice, or have common misconception about "Equals" being very special. Clarifying that could be a way to make question more ok. Showing research (like "there are a lot of questions like ... that talk about Equals vs. == for strings, but these are just objects") could have prevented downvotes and possibly made question more scoped.

And downvotes could be coming from perceived lack research - i.e. basic search for ["C# Equals vs =="](https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20equals%20vs%20%22%3D%3D%22) gives good information that is not represented in the post.